# Eclipse IDE template key shortcut?

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse IDE, open "template" view, it has a button "Insert into Editor", how can I bind a key shortcut to it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using key combination `ctrl+Space` on a context ( for example text "main") will open the code template pane in your editor and you can use arrow keys to select the template you want to insert.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Ctrl+Space` twice to elicit the template dialog (usually comes with the desired template selected).