# is it possible to bind a keyboard shortcut a template (or snippet) in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, templates, keyboard, bind

is there a way to bind a shortcut key (**except ctrl + space**) to a template?
Example:
ctrl + k => System.out.println()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse IDE template key shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665179/eclipse-ide-template-key-shortcut)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665179/eclipse-ide-template-key-shortcut

Comment: Are you talking about the Java editor? You might use Java postfix completion for that, e.g. typing `"hi".sy` + Return will be expanded to `System.out.println("hi");`.

Answer (score 0):

With out-of-the-box Eclipse, I'm not aware of any way to do this.

However, if you install the "Emacs+" Eclipse plugin from the marketplace, you will have access to the following functions:

- `kbd-macro-bind-to-key`: Offer to bind last macro to a key when not defining or executing a macro
- `kbd-macro-call`: Call the most recent Kbd Macro
- `kbd-macro-cycle-ring-next`: Rotate the keyboard macro ring to the next macro (defined earlier)
- `kbd-macro-cycle-ring-previous`: Rotate the keyboard macro ring to the previous macro (defined later)
- `kbd-macro-end`: End the definition of a Kbd Macro
- `kbd-macro-end-or-call`: End the definition of a Kbd Macro, or execute the most recent Kbd Macro
- `kbd-macro-start`: Start the definition of a Kbd Macro
- `load-kbd-macro`: Load a saved Kbd Macro into this session
- `name-last-kbd-macro`: Give a command name (for the duration of the Eclipse session) to the most recently defined keyboard macro
- `save-kbd-macro`: Save a Kbd Macro to a file
- `view-kbd-macro`: View Kbd Macro

However, although I've used Emacs+ for many years, I've never really used the macro feature. I know it exists, and I just briefly experimented with it to verify it works.